# Did Sainsbury’s steal Alice’s water?

Tags: england-and-wales, theft

Alice purchases a jug of water and places it on the counter as he sits down to read a newspaper and eat his other purchased food. It comes time for the shop to close, and staff come to remind Alice that the store is closed and that he must leave. Alice leaves his water on the counter with the purchase receipt inside the handle of the milk jug.

The staff are then cleaning up around the store and see it and place it back on the shelves even though the receipt which they mindlessly picked out and tossed into the bin clearly showed that the pint of water had been purchased by *someone*.

Has the shop appropriated property belonging to another without making reasonable efforts to locate and contact the owner?

Comment: That jug of milk violates so many health and safety standards if put back to the cooler, that conversion or theft would be the least of the stores problem: Putting an item that was out of the cooling chain back into the cooler is a violation of a lot of laws already, fineable for huge amounts. The staff would more likely be tasked to throw out the jug.

Comment: What if it was still chilled?

Comment: [This safetly leaflet](https://www.food.gov.uk/sites/default/files/media/document/chilled-food.pdf) indicates: "If this is not possible, you can display food out of chilled storage for up to four hours, but you can only do this once." - that is for *display* - the jug was never on display, might have been out of the cooler for more than 4 hours and thus is not allowed to be re-admitted to the cooling chain, unless it is clearly less than 4 hours out of the cooling chain.

Comment: Is it a jug, or a carton?  Has it been opened, or is it still sealed?  Did Bob leave the store when asked, abandoning his jug/carton?  So many details lacking...

Comment: Definitely still sealed.

Comment: The edit doesn't help...

Comment: How doesn’t it?

Comment: 1) there's a reference to milk remaining. 2) there's a logical problem: water is usually sold in bottles without handles, leading to problems with where the receipt is actually stored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a store sell merchandise I've left in the store?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14273/can-a-store-sell-merchandise-ive-left-in-the-store)

Answer (score 1):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

**No.**

Alice bought (a jug of) water in the café. She left water in the jug, left the jug on the café counter (or table) and then exited the café (without asking to take the water with her) - these are signals that she 'abandoned' the water. It's the same as if she left a half-eaten sausage roll, a half-consumed coffee or crumbs from a Danish pastry.

[There's no 'theft' in taking something abandoned](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/98533/what-is-the-status-and-value-of-the-day-s-unsold-newspapers-being-put-out-for/98583#98583).

Had she entered the café with something she went on to leave in the café, perhaps she brought in four bags of shopping and left with three, or she left her umbrella, handbag, mobile phone or car/house keys, then it doesn't seem reasonable to immediately assume it was abandoned and we get into having to make a [reasonable effort](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85827/what-are-reasonable-steps-to-ascertain-or-contact-lost-propertys-owner-to-avoid/85836#85836) to find the owner.

Whether something has been 'abandoned' can sometimes be difficult to establish. A classic case is items in a household bin; or items left outside a charity shop or by the bins behind a charity shop ([Ricketts v Basildon Magistrates [2010] EWHC 2358](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWHC/Admin/2010/2358.html)). [Law SE had a question (and answer) about (not-)abandoned newspapers](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/98533/what-is-the-status-and-value-of-the-day-s-unsold-newspapers-being-put-out-for/98583#98583).

In the absence of case law, I suggest that in the scenario of a café or similar place, if the customer orders some food/drink, leaves some of it, pays the bill and exits the establishment, without signalling any further interest in the food/drink, it seems reasonable to assume the customer no longer has an interest in the food/drink and has abandoned it.